# Spring-boot ms with docker and healthcheck not working

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, microservices, health-check

Hellow world!

I have [this public repo](https://github.com/erickmob/spring-petclinic-microservices) with some springboot MS, docker file, compose, and architeture like this (few parts are missing):
[image]

If I run it locally, following the start up order on docker compose, i got this if I ping this URLS:

http://localhost:8888/actuator/health -> {"status":"UP"}

http://localhost:8762/visits -> Yahooo! Hello World From Visits Service!! :)running at port: 8300

http://localhost:8762/customers -> Yahooo! Hello World From Customers Service!! :)running at port: 8100

http://localhost:8761/actuator/health

http://localhost:9090/applications -> admin

So far, so good.

But when I try to docker-compose up it, then the problems starts.

Some services dependes on others, and to do that, I use the healthcheck approach:
[image]
[image]

But I'm getting this error:
[image]

Can any one tell me what I'm missing here to make it work starting after theirs healthcheck?

Comment: i've try to change de url to service-name but still not working